# Index notation proving identity

Tags: tensors

I am trying to prove the identity $\nabla\cdot(\phi\textbf{u})=\phi\nabla\cdot\textbf{u} + \textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\phi$ using index notation but I am a bit stuck.
I have so far written $\nabla\cdot(\phi\textbf{u})=\nabla_i(u^i\phi)$ and I am wondering whether I am allowed to just use product rule on what I have? 
Thanks.
Edu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla \cdot (\phi u) = \partial_i(\phi u_i) = \phi \partial_i u_i + u_i \partial_i \phi = \phi \nabla \cdot u + u \cdot \nabla \phi    $

I think that's right. But yeah, you just use the product rule.